# How do I remotely list files using Powershell without using an SMB share (winRM port only)?

Tags: powershell

I would like to run a Powershell command that prints all files recursively from a given directory.

I have a requirement of no SMB shares from my corp. Need to use WinRM port only. Because of this `\\host\folder` is not going to work.

Using Powershell's Get-ChildItem directly, did not work for me because of the above requirement.

Comment: Perhaps the summary of the question itself is too broad, but the summary with the description as it stands now, is not broad at all. I listed a specific use case of "No SMB shares"

Comment: I have corrected the question so that it now more specific instead of a generic "how to list remote files?" Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following function to list files for a given computer and directory. This function bypasses the SMB port by using Invoke-Command which uses the WinRM port. Using 'ls -r' below results in the files being printed in a condensed format which is nice (imo). Declaring ScriptBlock before executing Invoke-Command allows you to pass in variables without requiring param(...) inside the Invoke-Command script block, and it also cleans up the code a bit by separating the command and execution line.

```
function viewRemoteFiles($server) {

    Write-Host "viewRemoteFiles($server) - entry"

    $scriptStr = "ls -r $remoteBaseDir | ForEach-Object { `$_.FullName }"
    $scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($scriptStr)

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $MySecureCreds -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock

    Write-Host "viewRemoteFiles($server) - exit"
}
```

Comment: Please explain the downvote? The code is working perfectly.

Comment: If you wanted this to be a Q&A question, you should have posted it as such.  As it stands, your question and answer are bad.  They don't ask a specific question and they don't explain an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 192.168.1.5 -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem C:\ -Recurse } -Credential Get-Credential
```